# QT QTableWidget,How can I select text while the item is uneditable

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

well,This is what I want: I double click the item,then I can select the text I want to copy,meanwhile the text in item should be Unchangeable.
However,When I use setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers),I cannot select the text.
Anybody to help me!

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use an item delegate to modify the editor, and set it read-only, like this:

```
class ReadonlyDelegate : public QItemDelegate {
public:
    QWidget * createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        QWidget *w = QItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
        qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(w)->setReadOnly(true);
        return w;
    }
};

// [in setup of view]
myTable->setItemDelegate(new ReadonlyDelegate(myTable));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Finally It's soloved...My code is as below:

```
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>


class ReadOnlyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ReadOnlyDelegate(QObject* parent = 0) :QStyledItemDelegate()
    {

    }

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
        const QModelIndex& index) const override
    {
        QLineEdit* editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
        editor->setFrame(false);
        editor->setReadOnly(true);
        return editor;
    }

    void setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index) const
    {
        QString value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
        QLineEdit* spinBox = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        spinBox->setText(value);
    }
    void setModelData(QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model,
        const QModelIndex& index) const
    {
        QLineEdit* spinBox = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        QString value = spinBox->text();
        model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
    }

    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget* editor,
        const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
    {
        editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    }
};
```

and in ui:

```
ui.TableWidget->setItemDelegate(new ReadOnlyDelegate());
```

Comment: Actually I don’t understand these codes very well,But it works.who care...